Imagick (PHP) is returning following error “no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361”
I know there are similar question on Stackoverflow that's already answered.
But It did not fix my bugs, so Please Let me ask here.
I'm trying to make a proxy in PHP.
My code is worked in my local Environment (Mac OS),
Then I deployed on my Raspberry Pi Model 3 that running Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS.
And Got error that never got in local. so I thought some dependencies error.
so I tried these commands.
$ sudo apt install -y imagemagick php8.2-imagick
$ apt-get install libgraphicsmagick1-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
$ sudo apt install libmagickcore-6*

I will explain my code and debugging a little bit:
If $compress is 0, Image is not modified by Imagick just sent to client properly.
If $compress is 1 (or over) then It will return the following error:
An error occurred: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361

I searched a lot and I run some commands, but It did not fix it.
so I am here to asking.
My code:
<?php
try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/image.avif");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "My Cool User Agent Here");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://example.com/image.avif");

    // CURL SETTINGS HERE....

    $imageData = curl_exec($ch);
    $imageInfo = getimagesizefromstring($imageData);
    $mimeType = $imageInfo['mime'];

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($imageData !== false) {
        if ( $compress > 0 ) {
            // header need to be commented-out for read error.
            // header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
    
            $imagick = new Imagick();
            $imagick->readImageBlob($imageData);
            
            $originalWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth();
            $originalHeight = $imagick->getImageHeight();
            
            if ($originalWidth > 400 || $originalHeight > 400) {
                if ($originalWidth > $originalHeight) {
                    $newWidth = 400;
                    $newHeight = (int)($originalHeight * (400 / $originalWidth));
                } else {
                    $newHeight = 400;
                    $newWidth = (int)($originalWidth * (400 / $originalHeight));
                }

                $imagick->resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
            }
            
            echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
        } else {
            header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
            echo $imageData;
        }
        fclose($content);
    }
} 
?>

The Image I was trying to proxy & modifying using Imagick is hosted here:
https://stor.strangeuploader.xyz/53e4baa9-a842-452b-a334-276c133e879e/14da66b74afa2bc7425a2cf1cb7ea48a4fc1efa042a4a46556fd37bd151714ec.avif
Post Script:
My goal is create API that can proxy image and the API should have compression system for reduce user-bandwidth (only if user wish).
(I have removed a lot of lines that is not related to this question for keep my question simple & cool.)

Have you checked Imagick::queryFormats()? That seems a first logical step. Try it both on Mac OS and the Raspberry Pi, and see if there's an obvious difference with respect to the AVIF format.

Output of this code:
$formats = Imagick::queryFormats();
print_r($formats);

Output on Mac: https://pastebin.com/1qd5Pm0r
Output on Raspberry Pi: https://pastebin.com/Psxgxai0
Thanks for commeting!

Where is the error occurring?  What format?  Is it on the read or write? What do you get from "magick -version"?

@fmw42 If you check the previous comments you'll see that AVIF simply isn't supported on the Raspberry Pi.

Yes, File type is AVIF and I am trying to install support.
The difference between my Mac and Raspberry Pi is OS and the method I installed Imagick.
In Mac I used brew and pecl, however in Raspberry Pi I use APT.
I need a way to install support for it, Or I cannot?
(It can be my solution to stop using raspberry pi or rewrite my script in nodejs and use better things)
